# Получить информацию с сайта для авторизованных пользователей

Tags: java, post, httpclient

Добрый день.  Пытаюсь получить информацию с сайта для авторизованных пользователей. Авторизация проходит успешно, но информацию получаю как для неавторизованных пользователей. Использую httpclient, создала хранилище cookie, посмотрела запросы/ответы в дебагере. Вроде все ок.

```
BasicCookieStore store=new BasicCookieStore();

    CloseableHttpClient client=HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCookieStore(store)
                          .build();



    HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://loads.ati.su/Auth.axd");

    List<BasicNameValuePair> formParam= new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    formParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "user"));
    formParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
    formParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rememberMe", "true"));


    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParam));
    post.setConfig(config);

    try(CloseableHttpResponse response=client.execute(post)) {

        StatusLine line=response.getStatusLine();
        System.out.println("Authorization status="+line.getStatusCode()+": "+line.getReasonPhrase());

       }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    post=new HttpPost("http://loads.ati.su/api/loads");
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(JSONValue.toJSONString(contParam), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON ));
    post.setConfig(config);

    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    try(CloseableHttpResponse response=client.execute(post))
    {

        StatusLine line=response.getStatusLine();
        System.out.println("Get content status="+line.getStatusCode()+":"+line.getReasonPhrase());
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null) {
            try(
            FileOutputStream fot=new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
                entity.writeTo(fot);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("No content");
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

у вас 2 `post` запроса, 1й на авторизацию, 2й на запрос данных, нужно из первого `response` достать куку и добавить ее в `client`, т.к. во 2м запросе пустая кука

Comment: Вроде нет, куки после первого запроса сохраняются в хранилище BasicCookieStore store, которое привязано к клиенту, проверю еще раз